# jquery changing the actual css style

Tags: jquery

I have the following style definition thant can be dynamically changed.

```
<style id="templateCSS">
    #box_shipto_header{
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        padding:5px;
        }
</style>
```

In the following example (see fiddle) you can see that I have a padding box where a user can enter a new value. When they do my code will overwrite everything inside the #box_shipto_header{} and not simply changing only the padding declaration.

I understand that using the jquery html() method will overwrite the content but I don't know of other methods to do what I need.

So if you enter 10 in the box it should update the  id element like that:

```
<style id="templateCSS">
    #box_shipto_header{
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
        padding:10px;
        }
</style>
```

[see my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7V4TU/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsFiddle( http://jsfiddle.net/7V4TU/21/ )

```
$('#padding').blur( function()
{
    var currentCSS = $("#templateCSS").html();

    var beforePadding = currentCSS.substring( 0 ,  currentCSS.indexOf( "padding:" ) + 8 );
    var afterPadding = currentCSS.substring( currentCSS.indexOf( "padding:" ) + 8 );
    var removePadding = afterPadding.substring( afterPadding.indexOf( "px" ) + 2 );

    $("#templateCSS").html( beforePadding + $(this).val() + "px" + removePadding );
}); ​
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS method:

```
$(function () {
    $('#padding').blur(function () {
        $("#box_shipto_header").css("padding", $(this).val() + "px");
    });
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/matthewbj/5c5wX/

**EDIT** Using the CSS method will add the `style` attribute to the `#box_shipto_header` instead of changing it's CSS deceleration.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function(){
    $('#padding').blur(function(){
        $('#box_shipto_header').css('padding',$(this).val()+'px');
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/7V4TU/14/)